# React Native combine 2 Firestore collection in one Flatlist

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have 2 collections in Firestore to do FeedScreen like this

collection users (when user register App)

```
users = [
    avatar: '',
    email: '',
    name: ''
]
```

collection Post (when user create a post)

```
posts = [
   image: '',
   text: '',
   timestamp: '',
   uid: ''
]
```

I do `useState` with collection posts like this

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [post, setPost] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of users

useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const post = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        post.push({
          key: doc.id,
          name: doc.data().name, //want name from collection users
          text: doc.data().text,
          timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
          avatar: { uri: doc.data().avatar }, //want avatar from collection users
          image: { uri: doc.data().image },
        });
      });

      setPost(post);
      setLoading(false);
    });

  // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
  return () => subscriber();
}, []);

if (loading) {
  return <ActivityIndicator />;
}
```

And the `Flatlist`

```js
<FlatList
  style={styles.feed}
  data={post}
  renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>;
```

I try to `useState` `collection('users')` and combine it with map but it gives error

I would like to display feed to flatlist with all of the data in the post and fetch avatar and name from users collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `new array` from 2 collection lists,  `.data` is what you need in the below example.

```
const users = [
  {
    id: “”,
    avatar: “ “ ,
    email : “ “ ,
    name: ""
  },
];

const post = [
  {
    image: "", 
    text: "", 
    timestamp: ,, 
    uid: ""
  }
];


const collectionUsers = {}:
users.forEach((item) => {
  if(collectionUsers[item.id] {
     collectionUsers[item.id] += item.avatar;
  } else {
    collectionUsers[item.id] = item.avatar;
  }
});


const data = post.map((item) => ({
   … item,
   avatar: collectionUsers[item.id]
})):

console.log(data);


<FlatList 
       data={post}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)} 
       renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
               <View> 
                     <Text> 
                            {item.avatar} 
                    </Text> 
              </View> 
      )} 
  />
```

Additional documentation that could help you:

https://www.tutorialguruji.com/javascript/combine-multiple-firestore-collection-in-one-flatlist-in-react-native/

https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage-with-flatlists

https://medium.com/@harshita.arun.1/firebase-to-flatlist-react-native-5281718969ab

Comment: Happy to help you @NatnichaChuen, It will also help me a lot if you up-vote my answer and mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot! Your reply was great and helped me . This Array join 2 collection and show in my console but not display on expo. i use item.avatar but on expo display only from collection post.